# Definition of Differentiation of Polynomials in Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, polynomials

> The formal derivatives of a polynomial are useful in discussing multiple roots. The **derivative** of the polynomial $f=\sum_{i=0}^n c_i\cdot x^i$ is the polynomial $f^{\prime}=\sum_{i=0}^n ic_i\cdot x^{i-1}$. We also use the notation $D(f) = f’$. Differentiation is linear, that is, $D$ is a linear operator on $F[x]$,

I think above notion of differentiation is different from definition of differentiation given in real analysis book. Because polynomial $f=(c_0,…,c_n,0,0,…)$ is a sequence, not a map. **Am I right?**

Comment: You are not right. No, the notion of differentiation presented is not different from the usual notion of differentiation. Also, a polynomial is not a sequence, it's a polynomial.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Usual notion of differentiation is defined on certain kinds of functions. Hoffman’s define polynomial over $F$ (which is different from polynomial function) as $f\in F[x]=\mathrm{span}(\{x^n|n\geq 0\})$, where $x=(0,1,0,…)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "where $x = (0,1,0,\dots)$"? If $x$ is a sequence, then what does $x^n$ mean?

Comment: Actually, I changed my mind. I do agree that Hoffmann's definition of differentiation is different from the real analysis definition, but I still find your reasoning problematic. I would say that Hoffmann's differentiation is defined on "formal polynomials" rather than on polynomial functions.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Hoffman proved lots of properties related to set $F^\Bbb{N}$. Like first he defined linear algebra over $F$. Then proved $F[x]$ is linear algebra over $F$. So vector multiplication makes sense. $x^n$ means multiply $x$ $n$ times with convention $x^0=1=(1,0,0,…)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Polynomial over $F$ and polynomial function over $F$ are two different things. Though if $|F|=\infty$, then set of all polynomial over $F$ is “algebra isomorphic” to set of all polynomial function over $F$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4526825/861687) is the proof. What do you mean by formal polynomial?

Comment: I'm not used to that definition, but that makes sense now. Yes, "formal polynomial" is another way of saying a "polynomial over $F$" that emphasizes that the polynomial is not being interpreted as a function (i.e. it is a polynomial only in "form").

Comment: Because definition differ, not everyone would agree that a formal polynomial (i.e. polynomial over $F$) is a sequence, but everyone would agree that it is not a map.

Comment: To @BenGrossmann's point, sequences are just one possible "implementation" of the concept of a formal polynomial. You should pretty much forget about it after seeing that it works once. Just like you wouldn't write out the definition of Kuratowski pair over and over again when working with ordered pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Different" is a very weak condition; yes, it is not literally the same operation as the derivative you met in real analysis, because it is defined on a different domain (abstract polynomials rather than differentiable functions). However:

1. It is *compatible* with the derivative you met in real analysis, in the sense that if the ground field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and we interpret polynomials as functions then the two notions of derivative return the same polynomial; there's a reason we're calling this operation the derivative and not something else.
2. It can be defined in a way that makes it look much more like an actual derivative, over an arbitrary field, with no limits. Namely, adjoin an infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ satisfying $\varepsilon^2 = 0$; then the formal derivative is $f'(x) = \frac{f(x + \varepsilon) - f(x)}{\varepsilon}$. Try it!

Comment: I completely agree with your 1. point. If we use polynomial function over $F$, i.e. $f:F\to F$ such that $f(t)=\sum_{i=0}^n c_i\cdot t^i$, $\forall t\in F$, for some $c_0,…,c_n\in F$, then we can use our usual definition of differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, but only in a formal sense.

The problem with Hoffman's book is that it does not really explain the concept of a *polynomial*.

Chapter 2 introduces the vector space of *polynomial functions over a field $F$*. A polynomial function over $F$ is a function $f : F \to F$ which can be written in the form
$$f(x) = c_0 + c_1x +\ldots + c_nx^n$$
where $c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_n$ are fixed elements of $F$ (independent of the variable $x$).

The vector space of polynomial functions occurs in a a lot of examples in chapters 2 and 3, and there are no surprising insights here.

For $F = \mathbb R, \mathbb C$ each polynomial function $f$ has a derivative $f'$ in the sense of real / complex analysis which is again a polyomial function. It is given by
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h}. $$
If $f(x) = c_0 + c_1x +\ldots + c_nx^n$, then
$$f'(x) = c_1 + 2 c_2x + \ldots + nc_n x^{n-1} .$$

In chapter 4 Hoffman introduces a new concept: The *algebra $F[x]$ of polynomials over a field $F$*. He gives a concrete definition of $F[x]$ as the vector space of sequences $(f_0,f_1,f_2, \ldots)$ in $F$ such that $f_i = 0$ for almost all $i$. He then defines a mutiplication on $F[x]$ making it a linear algebra over $F$. Writing $x = (0,1,0,0\ldots)$, we get
$$(f_0,f_1,f_2, \ldots) = \sum_i f_ix^i . \tag{1}$$
Note that $x^i$ (= product of $i$ factors $x$) is the sequence having a $1$ at position $i+1$ and zeros at all other positions. Observe that $x^0$ is the multiplicative neutral element in $F[x]$ and thus one can write $x^0 = 1$, but one must not confuse this element with $1 \in F$.

The RHS of $(1)$ looks like a polynomial function, but it is not. Unfortunately Hoffman does not give any motivation for his definition of $F[x]$, and thus one can believe that a polynomial **is** a sequence in $F$. Okay, it may be a philosophical question what a polynomial **really is**, but one should understand the *algebraic purpose of $F[x]$*. This is beyond the scope of the book, let me only mention that the algebra of polynomials has a certain *universal property* characterizing it up to isomorphism of $F$-algebras. See section "Categorical characterization" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring.

Hoffman's $F[x]$ is just a concrete *model* of the algebra of polynomials over $F$, there are other constructions producing isomorphic algebras.

The space $P_F$ of polynomial functions over $F$ is also a linear algebra over $F$ (multiplication in $P_F$ is the ordinary multiplication of functions). What is the relation between $F[x]$ and $P_F$? Of course each sequence $f = (f_0,f_1,f_2, \ldots)$ in $F$ such that $f_i = 0$ for almost all $i$ induces the polymomial function
$$p_f : F \to F, p_f(x) =  \sum_i f_ix^i . \tag{2}$$
Note that the interpretation of $x$ in $(2)$ differs from that in $(1)$: In $(2)$ it is  a variable which can take any value in $F$, in $(1)$ it is a special sequence in $F[x]$.   We can easily verify that function
$$e : F[x] \to P_F, e(f) = p_f$$
is a homomorphism of linear algebras over $F$. It is obviously surjective.

If $F$ is finite, then $e$ is not injective because $F[x]$ is infinite, but $P_F$ is finite (there are only finitely many functions $F \to F$). But we have

- If $F$ is infinite, then $e$ is an isomorphism of linear algebras over $F$. That is, $P_F$ is another model of the algebra of polynomials over $F$.

In fact, it is well-known that non-zero polynomial functions in $P_F$ can have only finitely many roots. If $e$ would not be injective, then there would be a non-zero polynomial $f \in F[x]$ such that $p_f = 0$. Thus $p_f$ is a non-zero polynomial function having inifitely many roots, a contradiction.

In $F[x]$ we have the formal derivative
$$D : F[x] \to F[x], D(\sum_i f_ix^i) = \sum_i (i+1)f_{i+1}x^i .$$

For $F = \mathbb R, \mathbb C$ we have the "analytic derivative"
$$D_a : P_F \to P_F, D_a(f) = f' .$$

Clearly
$$e \circ D = D_a \circ e$$
which means that formal and analytic derivative agree under the isomorphism $e$. But as said above, we may take $P_F$ as an alternative model of the algebra of polynomials over $F$, and if we do so, formal and analytic derivative are literally the same.

For other fields there is no analytic derivative of polynomial functions, we only have the formal derivative. However, see Qiaochu Yuan's answer how a surrogate of analytic derivative can be defined for arbitrary $F$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the long and elaborate answer. Yup, Hoffman’s gives concrete definition of $F[x]$. Some linear algebra book don’t precisely define polynomial. They just write $F[x]$ or $F[X]$, and call $X$ an intermediate value. Which I don’t feel satisfy. I also like your proof of injectivity of $e$. Hoffman’s proved it using lagrange’s interpolation formula. I did it using constructing an inverse map.